# Difference between 他给妈妈打电话” and “他打电话给妈妈”

Tags: grammar, difference, sentence-structure

I learned that the sentence pattern is A 给 B + something: "他给妈妈打电话”
but recently I saw  this 他打电话给妈妈. Are both grammarly correct?
Thanks is advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both are correct. Use them depending on which information you want to present first. A third possibility is 他打给妈妈一通电话, but 一通 cannot be omitted here.